# How change field of reused component in Qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I have the following code. I need to set different "model" field for different TableViews. How can i do this?

I need override "model" field for every TableView. It is possible?

```
// main.qml
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window

    TabView {
         Tab {
             title: "Tab 1"
             MyTable {}
         }
         Tab {
             title: "Tab 2"
             MyTable {}
         }
     }
}
```

.

```
// MyTable.qml
MyTableView {
    TableView {
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "number"
            title: "Number"
        }
        model: MyModel
    }
}
```

The next code is correct but too long.

```
// main.qml
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    TabView {
         Tab {
             title: "Tab 1"
             TableView {
                 TableViewColumn {
                     role: "number"
                     title: "Number"
                 }
                 model: MyModel_1
             }
         }
         Tab {
             title: "Tab 2"
             TableView {
                 TableViewColumn {
                     role: "number"
                     title: "Number"
                 }
                 model: MyModel_2
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You should clarify your question if you expect for the answer.

Comment: @dzukp Are you implying that you want a different model for each `MyTable`? So in `main.qml`, every time you create an instance of `MyTable {}`, the model can be changed?

Comment: @John Law you are right. I want change model for each `MyTable {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a property alias for the model. First set an id for the `TableView` then hook up its model.

```
// MyTable.qml
MyTableView {
    property alias model: tableView.model

    TableView {
        id: tableView
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "number"
            title: "Number"
        }
        // model: MyModel // redundant in most cases
                          // unless you want to have a DEFAULT model
    }
}
```

And use `model` in each `MyTable` item like so:

```
// main.qml
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window

    TabView {
         Tab {
             title: "Tab 1"
             MyTable { model: MyFirstModel }
         }
         Tab {
             title: "Tab 2"
             MyTable { model: MySecondModel }
         }
     }
}
```